# Разница ++i и i++ в цикле for

Tags: php, php5

Написал так:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=5; $i++){
 echo $i."<br>";
}
```

получил результат:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

и так:

```
for($i = 0; $i<=5; ++$i){
 echo $i."<br>";
}
```

получил результат:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Как видите, результаты идентичны.

Так в чем же разница между постфиксным и префиксным инкрементом в данном случае (в цикле `for`)?

Comment: А если по сути, то постфикс и префикс работает в операциях с разным приоритетом выполнения там где есть возможность выставить разный приоритет вычисления. А в цикле for не может возникнуть такая ситуация, поэтому оно так и работает.

Answer (score 4):

Различие между постфиксным и префиксным операторами инкремента состоит в возвращаемом значении выражения. Так как в приведенных примерах циклов результаты выражений не используются, то для циклов никакой разницы нет. В циклах используются значения переменной `$i` уже после вычисления выражений с инкрементами.

Сравните ваши циклы `for` с циклами `while`

```
$i = 0;

while ( ++$i <= 5 ){
 echo $i."<br>";
}
```

и

```
$i = 0;

while ( $i++ <= 5 ){
 echo $i."<br>";
}
```

В этих циклах уже используются результаты вычисления выражений с инкрементом.

Было время, когда вопрос, как писать в цикле `for` выражение инкремента либо как `$i++` или `++$i` вызывал серьезный интерес с точки зрения оптимизации кода на различных языках программирования. Но сейчас компиляторы и интерпретаторы настолько продвинулись вперед, что обычно генерируют один и тот же объектный код, когда значение выражения не используется.

Answer (score 1):

Почему Вы думаете что в данном случае будет разница?
Польза от этих форм видна только если нужно поменять порядок выполнения в составной инструкции.

Пример:
Инкремент имеет б**о**льший приоритет, чем плюсы/минусы, поэтому вычисление будет уже с инкрементированным значением:

```
$i = 0;
5 +++ $i; // 6
```

Здесь же сначала результат будет вычислен, только потом произойдёт инкремент:

```
$i = 0;
5 + $i++; // 5
```

---

В Вашем случае выполняться только одна инструкция (собственно, сам инкремент), поэтому разницы нет.

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае разницы никакой нету

http://www.php.su/learnphp/operators/?prior Ссылка на ответ к вопросу автора

Comment: Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.